# RDP not working in Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, remote-desktop

For some weird reason, RDP (remote desktop connection) is not working between my PC and laptop. Here is the scenario:

PC: Windows 10 Pro. Connected to the router through wire.

Laptop: Windows 10 Home. Connected to the router through WIFI.

RDP is enabled and is in firewall allowed list on the laptop. The connection is set as **Private Network** on both machines. I have even joined both machines to the same HomeGroup. I can access laptop's shared folders on the PC. It's only RDP that is not working. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Home does not have an RDP server, only client. The RDP server is not part of the home license.